# I need to profile a local Tomcat Java Application with Visual VM, but Profile tab is disabled

Tags: java, tomcat, profiling, visualvm

I have to profile a local Tomcat web application with VisualVM, but when I start VisualVM and open Tomcat connection, the Profile option in Applications menu is disabled and I can't profile it.
I'm using VisualVM 1.3.8 and my `JAVA_HOME` points to JDK 1.8 folder. I'm starting Tomcat through Eclipse Kepler and in my Catalina.bat file I'm starting Tomcat with JDK 1.8 too. In Eclipse I'm working with JDK 1.8 as the default environment.
I have tried to change de TMP folder because I read about it in another issues like mine, but although I have now my TMP folder in C:\Temp directory, profile tab doesn't show.

What can I do? What things I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add VM options as follow, profile from remote in Visual VM.

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=XXXX

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

Comment: I have added yet that options in the startup.bat file:                                  set CMD_LINE_ARGS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false                                          but profile tab doesn't work

Comment: Check your port 8086 in using? I usually add these options in Eclipse

Comment: I have the same jmxremote configuration in the JVM and in Visual Vm. If I open the Tomcat connection in Visual VM, in the Overview panel the jxmremote.port, jmxremote.authenticate and jmxremote.ssl options are the same in JVM and System tabs.

Comment: The Sampler and Tracer plugins works well, my only problem is that Profile tab is disabled